# Read JSON content from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, json, uiwebview

I'm using a UIWebView to display a captcha. If the user enters the captcha correctly, then the server returns data using JSON serialization. I don't want the view to display this, instead I want to intercept the loads of the UIWebView, and if it returns JSON serialized data, I want to store that data and remove the UIWebView.

I was thinking of setting up a delegate to the UIWebView and use its webViewDidFinishLoad, but how do I get the content loaded?

Answer (score 8):

You may want to look into defining a `UIWebViewDelegate` and using
`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` to intercept the request and handle it.

In your case, you would evaluate the `NSURLRequest` and return `NO` to prevent the WebView from loading.  In turn, you would create a separate `NSURLConnection` with the same request, and set up a delegate to receive the (JSON) response.

Comment: @jarnoan would you like to share your code, i didn't get this answer

Answer (score 5):

I came up with this (perhaps not so beautiful) solution:

Instead of returning a json-only response, I use the same HTML template that I used for the captcha. If the captcha succeeds, I send the json I want to the HTML template, which displays it in a hidden div with an ID:

```
<html>
<body>

{% if captcha_success %}

<div id="json" style="display: none">{"jsonvalue":"{{result}}"}</div>

{% else %}

// display captcha as usual

{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

and then I can get the contents in webViewDidFinishLoad by using:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
NSString *res = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('json').innerHTML"];
NSDictionary *json = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:[res dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:nil];
// more stuff
}
```

Generally I think it was pretty easy and straight forward to implement.